# Angularjs for loop with ng-repeat strange issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a simple array and a `ng-repeat` :

```
<p ng-repeat="person in persons">
  Hello {{person}}!
</p>
```

But when I generate it with for loop, the result is very strange! The `ng-repeat` doesn't print in order. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmqwjE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-repeat` for objects `{}` itself does not provide displaying with order (in most cases elements have order, but not in 100%) - in case of object, key is `String`, so they are ordered as string (`["1", "11", "2"]`) - but JS at all does not preserve order of `{}`, so even if they are displayed in any order, someday it may break without any big reason (browser update etc). Just use Array which are ordered, where sort is more *natural* (keys are `number`), check Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmJyGX Or use [orderBy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) with additional field, like `id`. My advice is, if you care about order, always use `[]` instead of `{}`, cause it always will work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In your JS (on code pen) you have:

```
$scope.persons = {};
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    $scope.persons[i] = i;
}
```

You are initiating `persons` as an object. Change to  `$scope.persons = [];`

Answer (score 2):

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.persons = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.persons[i] = i;
       $scope.results = angular.toJson($scope.persons)
        }

  //$scope.persons = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmVaZV?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

With a recent version of angular (1.6.0 for example), it doesn't happen.
You use an old version (1.1.5), it seems that this version sort by default the array.